# Is plain text in index.html secure?

Tags: bash, security, apache-httpd

So I would like to know if anybody can access my LAMP if I just write some plaintext in the index.html file, so that when somebody accesses my_ip:port they will be greeted to the text in that file.

I know everybody can read what's in that plaintext file, that's not my security concern.

My concern is whether or not somebody can run any scripts to affect my server or do anything because of it.

The reason I'm doing this is because I want an encrypted message to be visible on my lamp server, so that I can do some other stuff from there.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the M and the P parts of your LAMP stack, although Apache had a vulnerability recently, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting plain text into the file is no less (or more) secure than putting HTML there. As far as the server is concerned, HTML *is* plain text: what gets sent over the wire is exactly the `<html>...</html>` bits written in the file.

There may be *other* security issues in play for your scenario, but this isn't one of them.

I would, however, encourage adapting your web server configuration so that the file is served as text/plain instead of text/html for technical correctness, though the practical differences are pretty minimal (browsers will probably render it in fixed-width instead of variable).